# Soundmanager 2 : Stop a playing sound when playing another

Tags: javascript, html, audio

> `

```
soundManager.onload = function() {
 // soundManager.createSound() etc. may now be called
 soundManager.createSound({
 id:'myMp3', url:'audiofiles/my.mp3', onfinish:function()  
 {
 //window.location.href='index.html'
 }
 });
soundManager.createSound({
 id:'yMp3', url:'audiofiles/y.mp3', onfinish:function()  
 {
 //window.location.href='index.html'
 }
 });  
 };
```

`

Hi here I have created two sounds, which will be played with onClick event of two different links. When one sound is playing, and I click another link, both sound play simultaneously, I want to know how to stop playing the previous sound when a new one is triggered!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to keep references to the sounds once they're made. For example:

```
sounds = [
 new Audio("audiofiles/my.mp3"),
 new Audio("audiofiles/y.mp3")
];

sounds[0].play();
```

You can add in fancy event listeners via sounds[0].addEventListener. For pausing on play, use:

```
sounds[0].addEventListener("play", function() {
  sounds[1].pause();
});
```

Alternately:

```
document.getElementById("presstoplaysound").onclick = function() {
  sounds[1].pause();
  sounds[0].play();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".close-reveal-modal").click( function() {
    soundManager.stopAll();
});
```

Comment: Can you add some more description?